# Constructing a matrix given a kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm not sure if this would be a right way, but i would plug in points so the equation equals zero such as the points (1,1,-1) and use that as a linear combination of columns.

\begin{matrix}
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is defined as all the solutions to the problem

Ax=0 <=>

- a11*x1 + a12*x2 + a13*x3 = 0
- a21*x1 + a22*x2 + a23*x3 = 0
- a31*x1 + a32*x2 + a33*x3 = 0

so if you just set a21=a22=a23=a31=a32=a33=0
and a11=1; a12=2; a13=3 then you get the equation for the plane